# JSpinner Update

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, tablecelleditor

I creates a dataTable and cellEditor form one column. This column is simple jSpinner. I have the following problem. When I enter some value in the spinner and select the another row, the value in the previous row won't be changed. If I press , it'll done. If I select  or  button, it will done too. But if I enter value and change selection, it won't be done. Help, please. Here is the CellEditor code.

```
public class DurationTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{

final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();

// Initializes the spinner.
public DurationTableCellEditor() {
    spinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(1,1,50000,1));        
}

// Prepares the spinner component and returns it.
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    spinner.setValue(new Integer(value.toString()).intValue());
    spinner.setCursor(null);
    return spinner;
}

// Enables the editor only for double-clicks.
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject evt) {
    if (evt instanceof MouseEvent) {
        return ((MouseEvent)evt).getClickCount() >= 1;
    }
    return true;
}

// Returns the spinners current value.
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return spinner.getValue();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you're updating your data model, but one approach would be to implement `ChangeListener` in your `CellEditor`, much as this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) implements `ItemListener`. For reference, see [*How to Use Tables: Using Other Editors*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor). In particular, look at `fireEditingStopped()`. Finally, you'll need a corresponding `TableCellRenderer`.

Answer (score 0):

do `commitEdit()`

```
// Returns the spinners current value.
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    spinner.commitEdit();
    return spinner.getValue();
}
```